# Why did Carbide say that Béla Bartók was from Vedmediv?

Tags: ukrainian-language, andriy-lyubka, carbide

*Carbide* mentions in passing that the composer Béla Bartók "hailed from Vedmediv" (which is, of course, entirely fictional). He was actually from Nagyszentmiklós, which was then in Hungary but is now evidently in Romania. It also pointed out that he had a Hungarian name (which is a somewhat strange thing to point out given that he was, in fact, Hungarian).

He evidently briefly lived in Vynohradiv, Ukraine at one point, though, after his father died; is the book referring to that period in his life? (Even that doesn't exactly make sense to me, given that he moved to Slovakia later, so it would seem strange to say that he "hailed from" there).

It also claimed that he composed for the Boston Symphony Orchestra for "many years," but Wikipedia only mentions him composing a single work for them (which was evidently the last work he actually completed before he died).

Can someone clarify? Did the author have a literary purpose in this, or did he just mix up his history somewhat? Or was it a little of both?

Comment: look at [this](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/society/2015/11/151119_book_2015_reader_review_lyubka4) with the help of translator. It seems that in the original it is a fictional composer Bale ("Бейл"). Is he really named "Béla Bartók" in the book you are reading?

Comment: @Andra Yes, that's definitely how it's rendered in English (albeit without the diacritical marks, just in "standard" ASCII characters). At least some of the details more or less match his life; for example, he did go the U.S. and compose music for the Boston Symphony Orchestra (although Wikipedia only mentions one work that he composed for them - it didn't mention a multiyear collaboration).

Comment: no, in original it's not explicitly Bela Bartok, see https://coollib.net/b/384617-andriy-lyubka-karbid/read